Weird behavior when using Parallelize with LieART
I want to perform computation with the LieART package and Parallelize some long computation. But I run into the following strange unexpected behavior.
Consider a simple list generators = {J[-RootOmega[A][2]][$n_]}. Here RootOmega[A][n] is the built-in function in LieART, representing the weight $n \omega_1$.
Then I construct a simple rule
rule = J[a_][n_] :> g1[J[-RootOmega[A][2]][$n_] == generators[[1]]] g2[
     MatchQ[J[a][n], generators[[1]]]] g3[J[a][n]];

where

g3 collect the found expression J[a][n]
g2 checks if the found expression matches with the entry generators[[1]]
g1 checks if the entry generators[[1]]] is indeed the hard coded J[-RootOmega[A][2]][$n_]

Now I run the following code
Table[J[-RootOmega[A][2]][3] /. rule , {i, 1}] // Parallelize
(* returns {g1[True] g2[False] g3[J["(-2)"][3]]} *)

Table[J[-RootOmega[A][2]][3] /. rule , {i, 1}]
(* returns {g1[True] g2[True] g3[J["(-2)"][3]]} *)

Note that the g2 checks differ between the two lines of code.
My question: When Parallelize is used, why would the found expression (which is shown in g3 to be J[-RootOmega[A][2]][3] (where "(-2)" is the printed -RootOmega[A][2])), not match with generator[[1]]?
===
for reference, I collect here the code for RootOmega
LieART`Private`f_ "(LieART`Private`label__)" ^:= 
 RootOmega[
   LieART`Private`algebraClass] @@ (LieART`Private`f \
{LieART`Private`label})

"(LieART`Private`label1__)" + "(LieART`Private`label2__)" ^:= 
 RootOmega[
   LieART`Private`algebraClass] @@ ({LieART`Private`label1} + \
{LieART`Private`label2})


RootOmega /: 
 MakeBoxes[RootOmega[_][LieART`Private`label__], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{"LieART`Private`DisplayLabelCommaSeparated", "[", 
   "LieART`Private`label", "]"}]

RootOmega /: 
 MakeBoxes[RootOmega[_][LieART`Private`label__], TraditionalForm] := 
 TagBox[GridBox[{{"LieART`Private`label"}}, AutoDelete -> False, 
   GridBoxFrame -> {"ColumnsIndexed" -> {{{1, -1}, {1, -1}} -> 
        True}}, GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, 
     "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}], "Grid"]

RootOmega /: 
 MakeBoxes[RootOmega[_][LieART`Private`label__], LaTeXForm] := 
 RowBox[{"ToString", "[", 
   RowBox[{"\"\\\\rootomega\"", "<>", 
     RowBox[{"ToString", "[", 
       RowBox[{"{", "LieART`Private`label", "}"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]


Before providing a corrected code, it's crucial to pinpoint the exact cause of the unexpected behavior. Based on the information given, the issue seems to stem from potential inconsistencies in parallel evaluation of the rule.

@zeraouliarafik Thanks, you are right. I think the problem is I don't understand what the potential inconsistencies in parallel evaluation of the rule are, so I fail to pin point the cause. The rule seems rather simple, but with/without Parallelize the results are different. Any suggestions on how to pin point the exact cause?

Here are a few approaches to address this non-determinism:
Firstly try to Force order of evaluation: Use And to ensure g1 is evaluated before g2. This guarantees that the substitution happens before the matching check.
    rule = J[a_][n_] :> 
      If[J[-RootOmega[A][2]][$n_] == generators[[1]], g1[True] g2[True], g3[J[a][n]]];
for the next step try to simplify matching logic: Instead of relying on multiple checks, simplify the rule to directly match the desired expression:
rule = J[a_][n_] :> If[J[a][n] == generators[[1]], g1[True] g3[J[a][n]], g3[J[a][n]]];

For the final step you may need using Evaluate within Parallelize: Wrap the entire replacement rule with Evaluate to force symbolic evaluation on the main thread before sending it to the parallel kernels. However, this can be less efficient for large expressions.
Table[Evaluate[J[-RootOmega[A][2]][3] /. rule], {i, 1}] // Parallelize

Here is my suggested corrected code it may work based on the above steps:
(* Placeholder functions for J and RootOmega *)
J[x_][n_] := x^n
RootOmega[A_][n_] := n

generators = {J[-RootOmega[A][2]][$n_]};

rule = J[a_][n_] :> If[J[a][n] == generators[[1]], g1[True] g3[J[a][n]], g3[J[a][n]]];

Table[J[-RootOmega[A][2]][3] /. rule, {i, 1}] // Parallelize


Thanks for the explanation. After some playing around, in the end I use ParallelEvaluate[Import["my packages"]], which now works perfectly.
